# Picker Title color is unchangeable

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

using xamarin forms (pcl)

creating Picker

```
<Picker x:Name="Branches" 
  TextColor="White" Title="Click to choose Branch"
  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
  SelectedIndex="{Binding Branches}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Id</x:String>
        <x:String>Name</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Why is the `TextColor` of the `Title` black even tough I explicitly set it to white in XAML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Update: Xamarin.Forms v3.6

[Xamarin.Forms v3.6 introduces `Picker.TitleColor`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4701).

It is now possible to set the Picker's `TitleColor` directly without needing a workaround.

#### XAML

`TitleColor="Red"`

```
<Picker x:Name="Branches" 
  Title="Click to choose Branch"
  TitleColor="Red"
  TextColor="White" 
  Grid.Row="3" 
  Grid.Column="1"
  SelectedIndex="{Binding Branches}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Id</x:String>
        <x:String>Name</x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

#### Code

`myPicker.TitleColor = Color.Red`

```
var myPicker = new Picker
{
    TitleColor = Color.Red
};
```

---

## Explanation

Xamarin.Forms does not allow you to set the color of `Picker.Title`.

## Work Around

Add the title text as the first item in `Picker.Items`.

Then, set the initial `Picker.SelectedIndex` to 0. This will show the first item in `Picker.Items`(aka our title) on the screen by default when the page loads.

Then, add an event handler to `Picker.SelectedIndex` to prevent the user from selecting the title. It will check to see if the user selected the first item in `Picker.Items` (aka our Title), and, if `true` automatically change `Picker.SelectedIndex` to  `1`.

```cs
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PickerTitleColor
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            var picker = new Picker();
            picker.Items.Add("Select an item");
            picker.Items.Add("Item1");
            picker.Items.Add("Item2");
            picker.Items.Add("Item3");
            picker.TextColor = Color.Red;
            picker.SelectedIndex = 0;

            picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, e) => 
            {
                if (picker.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    picker.SelectedIndex = 1;
            };

            var content = new ContentPage
            {
                Title = "Custom Picker Title Color",
                Content = picker
            };

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: "iOS and Android have dictated that the picker title must always be gray to indicate to the user that no item in the list has been selected.".
But the gray could be a problem with non-white backgrounds, it's surely a bad decision it restricts developers to define their own themes.